# wso2 ei server, error 403 forbidden, Does not access the core, error:required token is missing from the request

Tags: wso2, bpmn, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-business-process, wso2-esb

I am installing WSO2 EI 6.1.1

```
integrator --run : 
https://localhost:9445/carbon/admin/login.jsp -> OK

wso2serber.bat : EI-Business-Process Server 
https://localhost:9445/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp
Error 403 - Forbidden

[EI-Business-Process]  WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} -  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:192.168.1.11, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request)

and wso2serber.bat : EI-Analytics
https://localhost:9444/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp
Error 403 - Forbidden

 [EI-Analytics]  WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} -  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:192.168.1.11, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request)
```

How do I solve this problem? How do I make the Management Console of  wso2 Business Process Server under WSO2 WSO2 EI available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a known bug in latest JDK.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789

Use `JDK 8u144` instead.

**Edit:** Another workaround is disabling `compression` in tomcat.

1. Open the ca`talina-server.xml` file from the `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/` directory.
2. Set the compression parameter (under each of the connector configurations) to `off` as shown below:
   `compression="off"`
3. Restart the server.

Comment: This does not work for me, I have made these changes. Also, I have `jdk1.8.0_144`