# Error 403 - Forbidden while loging in to Siddhi CEP management console

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I stared Siddhi cep from terminal using  `./bin/wso2server.sh` and got the following error when I tried to log in using `admin` and `admin`

```
[2018-01-21 20:56:25,707]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://192.168.1.84:9443/carbon/
[2018-01-21 20:56:35,251]  WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} -  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:192.168.1.84, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request)
[2018-01-21 20:57:01,024]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  Starting polling event receivers
```

I am using the latest version

```
amar@admin:~/Documents/wso2cep
./wso2server.sh version
WSO2 Complex Event Processor v4.2.0
WSO2 Carbon Framework v4.4.9
```

Complete console output is as below , as it might be useful in debugging

```
    amar@admin:~/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0$ ./bin/wso2server.sh 
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,013]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,014]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Mac OS X 10.13.2, x86_64
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,014]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,014]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_144
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,014]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.144-b01,Oracle Corporation
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,015]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,015]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/tmp
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,015]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : amar, en-CA, America/Toronto
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,118]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,300]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} -  Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,348]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.util.ManagementModeConfigurationLoader} -  CEP started in Single node mode
[2018-01-21 21:20:14,382]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.template.manager.core.internal.ds.TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS} -  Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2018-01-21 21:20:15,760]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} -  Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9711
[2018-01-21 21:20:15,764]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} -  Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9611
[2018-01-21 21:20:15,769]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Server 
[2018-01-21 21:20:15,944]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 58ms
[2018-01-21 21:20:16,073]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2018-01-21 21:20:17,601]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JDBCReporterBuilder} -  Creating JDBC reporter for Metrics with source 'admin', data source 'jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB' and 60 seconds polling period
[2018-01-21 21:20:17,602]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} -  Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2018-01-21 21:20:17,606]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2018-01-21 21:20:17,610]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JDBC reporter for Metrics
[2018-01-21 21:20:19,741]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2018-01-21 21:20:20,176]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2018-01-21 21:20:24,970]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2018-01-21 21:20:26,225]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2018-01-21 21:20:26,225]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,201]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Repository       : /Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,204]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceHolder} -  Kafka input event adaptor waiting for dependent configurations to load
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,229]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantLoadingConfig} -  Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,239]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,340]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener} -  HTTP port        : 9763
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,340]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener} -  HTTPS port       : 9443
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,411]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.simulator.core.CSVFileDeployer} -  CSV file events.csv deployed successfully.
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,530]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/STRATOS_ROOT].File[/Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/STRATOS_ROOT]
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,595]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/inputwebsocket].File[/Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/inputwebsocket.war]
[2018-01-21 21:20:28,630]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/outputwebsocket].File[/Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/outputwebsocket.war]
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,512]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.filter.AnnotationSizeOfFilter} -  Using regular expression provided through VM argument net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ignore.pattern for IgnoreSizeOf annotation : ^.*cache\..*IgnoreSizeOf$
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,516]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine} -  Using user supplied filter @ jar:file:/Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/shindig/WEB-INF/lib/shindig-common-2.5.2.jar!/org/apache/shindig/common/cache/ehcache/SizeOfFilter.txt
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,527]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.JvmInformation} -  Detected JVM data model settings of: 64-Bit HotSpot JVM with Compressed OOPs
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,757]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader} -  Extracted agent jar to temporary file /Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/tmp/ehcache-sizeof-agent2759891841290270949.jar
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,757]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader} -  Trying to load agent @ /Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/tmp/ehcache-sizeof-agent2759891841290270949.jar
objc[20166]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1051484c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10d4024e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,762]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine} -  using Agent sizeof engine
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,823]  INFO {net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine} -  using Agent sizeof engine
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,846]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.features.FeatureRegistry} -  Resources from res:features/features.txt are loading.
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,853]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.common.xml.XmlUtil} -  The XML processor being used does not support secure parsing.
[2018-01-21 21:20:30,854]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.common.xml.XmlUtil} -  Document builders are being reused.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,003]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.features.FeatureRegistry} -  Resources from res:features-extras/features.txt are loading.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,016]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.features.FeatureRegistry} -  Resources from res:wso2features/features.txt are loading.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,023]  WARN {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.features.FeatureRegistry} -  The container.site.gadget feature with definition at res:wso2features/container.site.gadget/feature.xml is being overridden.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,104]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.config.JsonContainerConfigLoader} -  Resources from containers/default/container.js are loading.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,104]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.config.JsonContainerConfigLoader} -  Container configuration containers/default/container.js is being read.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,505]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth2.logger.FilteredLogger} -  Using random key for OAuth2 client-side state encryption
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,506]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth2.logger.FilteredLogger} -  OAuth2CrypterProvider constructor
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,513]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth.OAuthModule} -  The OAuth signing key from res://wso2carbon.pem is loading.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,515]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth.OAuthModule$OAuthCrypterProvider} -  Using random key for OAuth client-side state encryption
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,515]  INFO {org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth.OAuthModule} -  A random key for OAuth client-side state encryption is being used.
[2018-01-21 21:20:31,651]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/shindig].File[/Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/shindig.war]
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,316]  INFO {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.app.mgt.TomcatJaggeryWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/portal].File[/Users/amar/Documents/wso2cep-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal]
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,330]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} -  Thrift Server started at 0.0.0.0
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,340]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} -  Thrift SSL port : 7711
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,343]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} -  Thrift port : 7611
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,372]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,391]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,437]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.service.impl.TaskServiceImpl} -  Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,489]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,520]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Complex Event Processor-4.2.0
[2018-01-21 21:20:32,521]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 21 sec
[2018-01-21 21:20:33,080]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://172.17.195.210:9443/carbon/
```

**EDIT 1:** The [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494032/wso2-ei-server-error-403-forbidden-does-not-access-the-core-errorrequired-to) did not solve my problem

Open the `catalina-server.xml` file from the 
`<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/` directory.

Set the compression parameter (under each of the connector configurations) to off as shown below: `compression="off"`

Restart the server.

I did these changes but problem is still the same

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494032/wso2-ei-server-error-403-forbidden-does-not-access-the-core-errorrequired-to

Answer (score 0):

setting the compression off for all the ports [2 in this case] solved the issue as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installation+Prerequisites). Previously I was just setting compression once, that's why it was not working